# MemSql: a long enough query sql has truncated,change 'max_allowed_packet' has no effect

Tags: singlestore

i have a long enough sql,
example: "select customerID from customer where customerID  in (1,2,3,4,5,......50000000)",
when i executed it,then a exceptions throw out...,
i find memsql truncate my query sql, but i has changed the  Global VARIABLES "max_allowed_packet=1049999360,load_data_read_size=1049999360,load_data_write_size=1049999360" and restart memsql cluster, however the question of truncate as usual, help me pls. thanks。[image]

Comment: Surely there are ways to write 'sane' queries.. that query [assuming all integers between] is what, ~50M x 9chars? (~400-450Mbytes min in UTF8). I'd probably consider correcting queries that don't fit in the "default" 16Mb limit .. SQL Server has much lower limits by default, and not too many people complain there :}

Comment: it seems meaningless,but these customerids is a report point data, i need these millions of customerids to build my complex query sql,It's not simple select customerid only. thanks。

Answer (score 1):

You may be running into the limit on the number of constants in a query. It’s 1 million.  Before MemSQL 6.5 this would generate a syntax error instead of a more specific error referring to the limit. That limit isn’t configurable.

As others have noted this may not be the most effiecient way to run this query.  You may want to try building a temporary table and doing an in (select custid from temp) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,to build a temporary tables is a good idea,but this is a old online business,don't consider performance and don't want to change too much. so the simplest way is to change the big enough ' max_allowed_packet' for me,but i change‘max_allowed_packet’is no effect,What shall I do ? thanks very much.

Comment: As I mentioned above, the limit on number of numeric constants in a query isn't configurable.  Increasing max_allowed_packet won't help with when you have 50 million constants in your IN list.  I don't think there is a knob you can change that will allow this query to run without making some changes to it.